# Original Plotl.y map inverted North and South Korea

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

I am making a choropleth map using the [Plot.ly demo](https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/) and noticed that Plot.ly's global map inherently inverted North and South Korea. That is, on a map, North Korea's position is in the South, and the South Korea's location is in the North.

Of course, I can always act as if North is South, and vice versa, by entering data on the opposite vectors. However, this is a bit "unprofessional" communicating with others working on data entry.

When working with problems like this, is there a way to change the contents of the package myself?

Comment: Technically, plotly.js, which is the Javascript graphics library that the product Plot.ly uses is open source, so yes, you should be able to change the contents of the package.

Comment: *Of course, I can always act as if North is South* Please don't...this will cause geopolitical instabilities. EOF. Can you please add some plots as well?